# Is there any superstitious associations between the number eleven and evil?

Tags: superstition, numerology, evil

We're all familiar with various superstitious ideas that consider the number 13 unlucky. But is there any such associations with the number 11? I've found Kabbalistic sources that connect the number 11 to the *sitra achara* ("the other side" in Aramaic) which is the "dark side" or the "side of evil." Are such ideas found in other sources?

Comment: Ten is a very important number in Judaism (numerical value of the divine initial *yod*, Noah being the tenth from Adam, number of fingers, plagues, commandments, Sefirot, etc). Eleven, which goes beyond ten, signifies the beyond, or other (*ahara*).

Answer (score 1):

The only one I can think of is in the Babylonian [Enuma Elish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En%C5%ABma_Eli%C5%A1). The goddess Tiamat creates eleven monsters to battle the other gods.